# UISlider doesn't animate while it's superview is scrolling

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am making an easy music player, and I have a UISlider as it's progress bar.
Upon music starts, I fire a timer (0.01 interval) to notify the slider and make the slider change it's value accordingly.

Everything goes well except while the slider's superview (in this case a scrollview) is moving, the slider keeps still even though the timer is working well.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, NSTimers won't fire when a scroll view is scrolling. You have to add the timer to the mainRunLoop for NSRunLoopCommonModes:

```
    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:yourTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```